# Checking your local host

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed xampp on my windows 8 did all the necessary functions from system32/drivers to httd conf and vhost file but when I call my web site on the browser I get this error please help

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] 
[1203] User username already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections' 
    in /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): 
    PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'username', 'password', Array) 
#1 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() 
#2 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 
#3 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLES', Array) 
#4 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(765): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLES', Array) 
#5 /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(114): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol('SHOW TABLES') 
#6 /home/username/pu in /home/username/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

Comment: Do you close the connections you establish after you're done with them?

Comment: Niet - This isn't necessary, as PDO/Mysql_* closes the connection automatically after it's finished. 
OP: Maybe your hosting provider has limited Mysql_ connections to X?

Answer (score 0):

This a PDO error, PDO is used to handle connection with your database. Here you probably open too much connection with your database (you probably create one instance each time you access you DB). You have to close you database or to use the singleton pattern with you class connection

Have a look here :

http://weebtutorials.com/2012/03/pdo-connection-class-using-singleton-pattern/

Comment: please be more specific im kinda new to this and really wanna get up and running...what is a singleton pattern

Comment: @KopanoUnityMaripane I added a link in my answer I hope this will help you. Otherwise a singleton class is a class who could be instantiated only one time.